Convergence in probability using "outer probability"
The following is from the book Asymptotic Statistics by van der Vaart.
Here, let $D$ be a metric space. $(\Omega_n, U_n, P_n)$ and $(\Omega, U, P)$ are probability spaces.
A sequence of arbitrary maps $X_n \colon \Omega_n \to D$ converges in probability to $X$ if $P^*(d(X_n,X) > \epsilon) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. The sequence $X_n$ converges almost surely to $X$ if there exists a sequence of (measurable) random variables $\Delta_n$ such that $d(X_n,X) \leq \Delta_n$ and $\Delta_n \to 0$ almost surely.
$P^*$ is called the outer probability in the book. First, I believed  $P^*(B) = \inf \{P(A) \colon A \in U(\text{i.e. A is measurable}), B \subseteq A\}$.
However, the problem with this is that $X$ is defined on some probability space $(\Omega, U, P)$ i.e. the domain of $X_n \colon \Omega_n \to D$ and $X \colon \Omega \to D$ are different. Hence, the set $d(X_n, X)>\epsilon$ would have to be something like $\{ (\omega, \omega') \in \Omega_n \times \Omega \colon d(X_n(\omega), X(\omega'))>\epsilon)$.
So here, what should be the correct definition of $P^*$? And also, with $d(X_n,X) \leq \Delta_n$, is $\Delta_n$ a random variable defined on $\Omega_n \times \Omega$?
Thank you.


In the book by van der Vaart and Wellner listed among the references for the chapter, convergence in outer probability and outer almost surely is defined for functions on the same space. There is also a generalization of convergence in outer probability to a constant that works with different probability spaces, but that does not work for convergence to more general functions.

@MichaelGreinecker so should it just be for functions on the same space?

Yes. With a possible exception for convergence to a constant, where there is no problem with different underlying probability spaces.
